# Use 'keys' as rule element label

Tags: c#, antlr4

In my project I write a language that is used to process key value pairs. So I have some rules to match multiple keys `keysList` and one for values `valuesList`. Now I want to use them in another rule

```
operationExpression
    :    keysList CompareOperator valuesList
    ;
```

Which works fine.

I thought it would be nice to name these rule elements `keys` and `values`

```
operationExpression
    :    keys=keysList CompareOperator values=valueList
    ;
```

When I now try to compile my project I get like a thousand errors complaining about a missing semicolon. When I looked into the generated code I found that Antlr gave strange names to the those contexts. I expected them to be `keys` and `values` but instead they seem to be every C# keyword (and values has some @s in between).

```
public KeysListContext structexterndoushortfloatwhileoperatorrefprotectedreadonlycontinueelsecheckedlockcatchifcasenewusingstaticvoidinsizeofbytedoublesealedfinallythisuncheckedisparamsenumexplicitasnulltruefixedtrydecimalobjectimplicitinternalprivatevirtualboolconststringforinterfaceunsafelongoutswitchdelegateforeachdefaultulonggotopublicstackallocoverrideeventclasstypeofbreakfalsevolatileabstractuintintthrowcharnamespacesbyteshortreturnbase;
public ValuesListContext @struct@extern@do@ushort@float@while@operator@ref@protected@readonly@continue@else@checked@lock@catch@if@case@new@using@static@void@in@sizeof@byte@double@sealed@finally@this@unchecked@is@params@enum@explicit@as@null@true@fixed@try@decimal@object@implicit@internal@private@virtual@bool@const@string@for@interface@unsafe@long@out@switch@delegate@foreachkey@ulong@goto@public@stackalloc@override@event@class@typeof@break@false@volatile@abstract@uint@int@throw@char@namespace@sbyte@short@return@base;
```

Every other name seems to be fine. Why does Antlr do this and why am I not allowed to use `keys` and `values` as rule element labels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug: [Issue 1125](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/issues/1125).

It seems that there's a map somewhere in which user-defined identifiers can clash with certain keys that already exist in the map (which include `keys` and `values`).

So you'll have to use different names while you wait for the bug to be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that's one way to tell you that you used reserved keywords as label names. As you already found out other names work fine, so use names instead that do not clash with your language's reserved words.

Comment: `keys` and `values` aren't reserved words in C# though.

Comment: Good point. Maybe they are invalid in this specific context? If other names work, why bother? To me it seems obvious that `keys` and `values` clash with something here.